# A good practices python decorator

Tags: python

I made decorators to cache the data and in particular to list the files contained in a cache file. I specify that my code works perfectly but I dont know if it is a good practice because I decorate a method of my class with my decorator "@ cache.listcachedir (...)" which in reality does not call upon my method but return a result (see code above).

My decorator (in cache.py):

```
def listcachedir(directory):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self):
            # Join base cache dir to directory
            fdir = self.locate(directory)
            if os.path.isdir(fdir):
                return os.listdir(fdir)
            else:
                raise CacheNotFoundError()
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

In my other py file:

```
class Analitics:

    def __init__(self, ):
        self.base_cache_dir = ".../..."
        ...

    def locate(directory):
        return os.path.join(self.base_cache_dir, directory)

    ...

class Analyzer(Analitics):

    def __init__(self):
        Analitics.__init__(self)

    @cache.listcachedir('my_cache')
    def getCacheList(self): return # Return any the wrapper return result

if __name__=="__main__":
    ana = Analyzer()
    print(ana.getCacheList()) # Works
```

Comment: Transforming a function is the entire point of a decorator.  What aspect of that are you concerned isn't a good practice?

Comment: @Samwise but the function is not transformed, it is completely replaced. The `func` argument is not used.

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that part.  That does seem a bit pointless.

Comment: It's the empty return which is a bit confusing and I want to know if it was a good practice ?

Comment: I say it's a bad practice because the decorator doesn't call the function/method, and is really doing something else…like adding a method in the case of a class.

Comment: I don't understand why you would do this instead of just defining a function (without the decorator indirection) and having your method call that.

Comment: I have simplified my use case. It allows me to follow the paths of my cache in all my derived classes transparently which uses each of the specific directories

Comment: The question can be argued on the basis of facts. It is not too opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the use of a decorator misleading here.

You don't use the `func` argument. I expect a decorator to do *something* with the function (or class) it decorates. Because if it does not, what's the point of defining the function that's being decorated?

You could write your code like this:

```
def make_cachemethod(directory):
    def cachemethod(self):
        fdir = self.locate(directory)
        if os.path.isdir(fdir):
            return os.listdir(fdir)
        else:
            raise CacheNotFoundError()

    return cachemethod

class Analyzer(Analitics): 
   getCacheList = make_cachemethod('my_cache')

   # more code here
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is indeed cleaner and less ambiguous.

Comment: @Martin13 you might also want to look into [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and [`functools.partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is bad practice because it's needlessly confusing.  You can define the function more simply as:

(cache.py)

```
def listcachedir(analitics, directory):
    # Join base cache dir to directory
    fdir = analitics.locate(directory)
    if os.path.isdir(fdir):
        return os.listdir(fdir)
    else:
        raise CacheNotFoundError()
```

and then:

```
class Analyzer(Analitics):

    def __init__(self):
        Analitics.__init__(self)

    def getCacheList(self): 
        return listcachedir(self, 'my_cache')
```

This does exactly the same thing (including separating the `listcachedir` implementation into its own module), but without all the confusing layers of indirection.